# Recommend me a good motherboard for my PC

Tags: motherboard

My current motherboard have failed bios update.

I got to change motherboard
The important specs are

```
3.00 gigahertz Intel Core i7-3770
Gtx 1060 video card
```

The old motherboard is ECS H61H2-M12 1.0

I  need a motherboard with the same slot for video card intel core etc. I need something that will work right off the bat without bios update. I want the system to be used at it's optimum. For example, I wonder if the clock frequency of the motherboard should be the same with the clock frequency of the i7

The PC specs are the following

```
Windows 10 Professional (x64) (build 10240)
Install Language: English (United States)
System Locale: English (United States)
Installed: 10/2/2015 2:25:25 PM
Servicing Branch: Current Branch (CB)
Boot Mode: BIOS (Secure Boot not supported) 
Operating System 
ECS H61H2-M12 1.0
Enclosure Type: Desktop 
System Model 
3.00 gigahertz Intel Core i7-3770
32 kilobyte primary memory cache
256 kilobyte secondary memory cache
6144 kilobyte tertiary memory cache
64-bit ready
Multi-core (4 total)
Not hyper-threaded 
Processor a 
Board: ECS H61H2-M12 1.0
Bus Clock: 400 megahertz
BIOS: American Megatrends Inc. 4.6.4 10/27/2011 
Main Circuit Board b 
1755.58 Gigabytes Usable Hard Drive Capacity
525.79 Gigabytes Hard Drive Free Space

TSSTcorp CDDVDW SH-222BB [Optical drive]

Generic Flash Disk USB Device (8.05 GB) -- drive 3
ST1000DM003-9YN162 [Hard drive] (1000.20 GB) -- drive 0, s/n S1D0F680, rev CC4C, SMART Status: Healthy
ST3500312CS [Hard drive] (500.11 GB) -- drive 2, s/n 5VVAE8XQ, rev SC13, SMART Status: Healthy
TS256GSSD370 [Hard drive] (256.06 GB) -- drive 1, s/n B968689423, rev N1114B, SMART Status: Healthy 
Drives 
8170 Megabytes Usable Installed Memory
```

Other restrictions, I want popular ones

Can fit 16 GB memory. 4 sata port is fine.

I want cost effective. So it should be a good motherboard. Should be roomy enough unlike my  ECS H61H2-M12 1.0

If possible I want to know my memory frequency and pick a motherboard with the exact same frequency so no wasted power.

Also in indonesia the popular motherboard is either asus or gigabyte. Others are fine but please explain why.

Comment: How many RAM slots do you need?

Comment: 16GB? I think 4 sata should be enough.

Comment: Not how much RAM you have/need, how many RAM slots  you need - how many "sticks" of RAM do you have?

Answer (score 2):

On the high end / Price range - You could always try [ASRock Z77 Extreme4 ATX LGA1155](http://pcpartpicker.com/product/VvMFf7/asrock-motherboard-z77extreme4). PCpartpicker doesn't indicate that the bios will need to be updated.

[The Intel DH67BLB3 Micro ATX LGA1155](http://pcpartpicker.com/product/bCR48d/intel-motherboard-boxdh67blb3) is a good micri ATX option. Its doesn't have as many sata ports as the ASRock, but it looks like there are enough to support your current build.

If these two options don't fit the bill. I would head over to pcpartpicker and put in your entire system minus the motherboard and see what options are compatible.  For a motherboard, I would try to stay in the realm of name brand and grab something with good reviews. Personally I'm a fan of MSI boards, don't know why. I've always used them for my intel builds and they seem to hold up well.

At the end of the day, there are alot of things you need to consider, form factor & sata ports & compatibility being the main things.